# Error when calling OpenSearch API in LocalStack: "exception while calling S3 with unknown operation"

Tags: docker, opensearch, localstack

I am trying to use `OpenSearch` through Localstack in my Symfony 6 project. The symfony project is running inside a docker container and using `opensearch-project/opensearch-php` package to interact with OpenSearch API.

Everything is working fine in my localhost but when OpenSearch API is being called in GitHub Workflow Action then I get following error

```
1) App\Tests\Integration\Api\CreatePostTest::testCreate
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Error><Code>InternalError</Code><Message>exception while calling s3 with unknown operation: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

It is very strange that calling OpenSearch API throws S3 exception.

Here is my code

**Docker Compose File**

version: "3.7"

```
services:
    opensearch:
        container_name: opensearch
        image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.1.0
        environment:
          - node.name=opensearch
          - cluster.name=opensearch-docker-cluster
          - discovery.type=single-node
          - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
          - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
          - "DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true"
        ports:
          - "9200:9200"
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        volumes:
          - '/usr/share/opensearch/data'

    localstack:
        image: localstack/localstack:latest
        container_name: localstack_aws
        ports:
            - '4566:4566'
        depends_on:
            - opensearch
        hostname: localstack
        environment:
            - SERVICES=s3
            - DEBUG=1
            - LS_LOG=trace
            - EDGE_PORT=4566
            - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
            - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2
            - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=not-a-real-key
            - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=not-a-real-secret
            - LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME=localstack
            - OPENSEARCH_CUSTOM_BACKEND=http://opensearch:9200
            - OPENSEARCH_ENDPOINT_STRATEGY=path
        volumes:
            - './docker/localstack:/var/lib/localstack'
            - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
        networks:
            default:

networks:
    default:
```

I am also able to fetch domain info which I have created

```
{
    "DomainStatus": {
        "DomainId": "000000000000/my-os-domain",
        "DomainName": "my-os-domain",
        "ARN": "arn:aws:es:us-east-2:000000000000:domain/my-os-domain",
        "Created": true,
        "Deleted": false,
        "Endpoint": "localstack:4566/opensearch/us-east-2/my-os-domain",
        "Processing": false,
        "UpgradeProcessing": false,
        "EngineVersion": "OpenSearch_2.5",
        "ClusterConfig": {
            "InstanceType": "m3.medium.search",
            "InstanceCount": 1,
            "DedicatedMasterEnabled": true,
            "ZoneAwarenessEnabled": false,
            "DedicatedMasterType": "m3.medium.search",
            "DedicatedMasterCount": 1,
            "WarmEnabled": false,
            "ColdStorageOptions": {
                "Enabled": false
            }
        },
        "EBSOptions": {
            "EBSEnabled": true,
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "VolumeSize": 10,
            "Iops": 0
        },
        "AccessPolicies": "",
        "SnapshotOptions": {
            "AutomatedSnapshotStartHour": 0
        },
        "CognitoOptions": {
            "Enabled": false
        },
        "EncryptionAtRestOptions": {
            "Enabled": false
        },
        "NodeToNodeEncryptionOptions": {
            "Enabled": false
        },
        "AdvancedOptions": {
            "override_main_response_version": "false",
            "rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index": "true"
        },
        "ServiceSoftwareOptions": {
            "CurrentVersion": "",
            "NewVersion": "",
            "UpdateAvailable": false,
            "Cancellable": false,
            "UpdateStatus": "COMPLETED",
            "Description": "There is no software update available for this domain.",
            "AutomatedUpdateDate": 0.0,
            "OptionalDeployment": true
        },
        "DomainEndpointOptions": {
            "EnforceHTTPS": false,
            "TLSSecurityPolicy": "Policy-Min-TLS-1-0-2019-07",
            "CustomEndpointEnabled": false
        },
        "AdvancedSecurityOptions": {
            "Enabled": false,
            "InternalUserDatabaseEnabled": false
        },
        "AutoTuneOptions": {
            "State": "ENABLE_IN_PROGRESS"
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if any other info is needed.